# How to open a draft pull request using Github API?

Tags: github, github-api

I have created a draft pull request using Github API. But how do I can its state from draft to open using GitHub API?

Answer (score 0):

Updating a created pull request to mark it as ready for review is not currently supported by the v3 or v4 versions of the GitHub API. It will likely be available in the future.